# cocos2d error while loading sprite

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am having a quite strange problem in loading a sprite that was previously correctly loaded. I get this error depicted in the XCode console:

```
CCTexture2D. Can't create Texture. UIImage is nil
Couldn't add image:test.png in CCTextureCache
```

I can not see what is changed  any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Do you see test.png in the project navigator ?  If yes, click on it, and make certain it is included in the target (show Utilities, at the top right, above the word 'view', the right button of that group of 3 buttons). Make certain that in the pane 'Target membership', your build target is selected. If not, well... you know what to do.

Also, as a 'personal rule', before trying anything when this sort of thing occurs, i tend to clean the target (including the project derived data), then a build and test again. Xcode can have its moments with respect to keeping track of files and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the file is named "test.png" and not "Test.png" because the iOS devices use a case-sensitive filesystem. The file also needs to be added to your Xcode project to the correct target.